# How access object's parameters through a method from another class (C#)

Tags: c#, methods

Hello I need your help..

I have a 2 classe called Book and Title and a constructor called Book(string A, string B, string C, string D) and in the main program class I call method AddCopy() that included in the Title Class see code from the main class below:

```
Book book1 = new Book("A", "B", "C","D");
book1.AddCopy(Copy copy);
```

Now my main question is: How can I access the A,B,C,D parameters in the AddCopy method?

Answer (score 2):

The parameters of the constructor call, A, B, C and D are all scoped within the constructor - that means that they are only available within the constructor.

To access their values from the AddCopy method you need to copy them to class level fields in the constructor.

So your Book class becomes something like:

```
public class Book
{
    private string _a;
    private string _b;
    private string _c;
    private string _d;

    public Book(string A, string B, string C, string D)
    {
        _a = A;
        _b = B;
        _c = C;
        _d = D;
    }

    public void AddCopy(Copy copy)
    {
        // within this method you can access the private fields, but there is no
        // way to access the A, B, C and D parameters of the constructor.

        string someString = _a + _b + copy.SomeProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just added to code to do that. Note that you are not accessing the parameters themselves, you do not affect the values outside the class, only their class copies. (you can affect the values outside but this is usually a bad idea - or at least something that should be carefully thought through)

Comment: @Andrew Well then the code you provided is incorrect. Could you please edit your question? This simple answer is that you expose those fields as public properties od the Book class. Then you need to reference an instance of the Book class from the Title class and get the values from the properties.